# Redux selector erroring when trying to export state in one slice but not another when the code is almost similar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, undefined

I am new to redux and I have created a slice called eventmodalSlice that is supposed to keep track of whether a modal in the app is open or closed. I get an error when I create a selector to export the state. The error says

**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.eventmodal')**

```js
import React from "react"
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

export const eventmodalSlice = createSlice({
    name: "eventmodal",
    initialState:{
        modalvisible: null
    },

    reducers: {
        Close: (state, action) => {
            state.modalvisible = action.payload;
        },

        Open: (state, action) => {
            state.modalvisible = action.payload;
        },

    }
});

export const  {Close, Open} = eventmodalSlice.actions;
export const selectEventModal = (state) => state.eventmodal.modalvisible;
export default eventmodalSlice.reducer;
```

I am not sure what causes this error in this specific slice because I have another slice called user slice which looks almost the same as this slice.

```js
import React from "react"
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { act } from "react-test-renderer";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState:{
        user: null
    },

    reducers: {
        Signin: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload;
        },

        Register: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload;
        },

        Signout: (state) => {
            state.user = null;
        }
    }
});

export const  { Signin, Register, Signout} = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**State.user.user does not error in this last snippet. This is what's most confusing since these snippets look pretty much the same unless I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated here.**

My store looks like this

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "./userSlice"
import eventmodalReducer from "./eventmodalSlice"

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer,
        eventmodal: eventmodalReducer
    },
});
```

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: export const selectEventModal = (state) => state.eventmodal.modalvisible;     this line

Comment: Ensure you export all of the reducers and the store after initializing it.
I had such an issue when my project's bundle size was significantly increased.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userSlice from "./userSlice"
import eventmodalReducer from "./eventmodalSlice"

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userSlice.reducer,
        eventmodal: eventmodalReducer
    },
});
export default store;
```

Comment: destrcuture the code as above  in the store.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './app/store';



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
<Provider store={ store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
  
);
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: your index.js should look like this.......after this the code should work perfectly fine

Comment: remember to include your other imports if any

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).